# Creating function handle from two vectors to pass to an integral function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, function-handle, simpsons-rule

I'm not sure if I'm being thick here, but I'm not used to function handles etc.

I am trying to find the integral of some raw accelerometer data i have, and was advised by a friend that using Simpsons might be the best way. So i found that MATLAB has the "quad()" function but it accepts a function handle as a parameter.

If i have two vectors, one for time, one for acceleration, how can i create them into a function handle to send to quad()?

Thanks

Comment: does the vectors depend on the same variable?

Comment: `trapz` is the built-in function for numerical integration using the Trapezium rule. Whilst the trapezium rule has a larger error than Simpson's rule for *continuous* functions, it will offer a good approximation for discrete data.

Answer (score 0):

Use one of these two

```
f = @(x) sin(x);
x = linspace(a,b,200);
y = f(x);               % values at f(x)

s1 = trapz(x,y);        % you can use trapz
s2 = integral(f,a,b);   % you can use integral
```

Compare the results. Experiment